# How to access unwanted save file name and delete it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, arcgis

I need to filter my raster image by a fixed threshold. So I use ILogicalOp functions. Whenever I use them, an output file will be saved on workspace, which is unwanted due to my large database. The saving happens exactly after `rasOut[i] = RMath.LessThan(inputRas[i], cons01)`. How can I prevent this? Or how to get saved file name and delete it? Any comments would be Appreciated?

```
private IGeoDataset[] CalcColdThreshold(IGeoDataset[] inputRas)
{
    IGeoDataset[] rasOut = new IGeoDataset[inputRas.Length];
    IGeoDataset emptyRas=null;
    ILogicalOp RMath;
    RMath = new RasterMathOpsClass();
    IRasterAnalysisEnvironment env;
    env = (IRasterAnalysisEnvironment)RMath;
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new RasterWorkspaceFactoryClass();
    IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(workSpace_save.Text), 0);
    env.OutWorkspace = workspace;
    IRasterMakerOp Rmaker = new RasterMakerOpClass();
    IGeoDataset cons01;
    Threshold_value = 15000;
    cons01 = Rmaker.MakeConstant(Threshold_value, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < inputRas.Length; i++)
    {
        rasOut[i] = RMath.LessThan(inputRas[i], cons01);
    } 
    return rasOut;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to save somewhere else, or not save at all?

Comment: It is not my final result, I don't want to save it but it is saved automatically. It occupy much space for no reason.

Comment: The problem is it has to go somewhere - if it's as big as you say, it's probably too much data to hold in memory. If you want to make it easier to clean up, I would point your `env.OutWorkspace` to a temporary location for the intermediate steps of the process and then delete the workspace once you're done.

Comment: I will appreciate if u write an example or line of code, How address to a temporary location?

Comment: I'm not actually a C++ programmer, just trying to provide some pointers to get you going since no one else seems to have any answers. :) I've just been reading the .Net docco, and found the [IScratchWorkspaceFactory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IScratchWorkspaceFactory2_Interface/0025000007zv000000/) interface, which might work nicely for you - instead of creating your `workspace` variable using `.OpenFromFile`, try creating a scratch workspace instead? It seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(disclaimer: I'm not actually a C++ programmer, just trying to provide some pointers to get you going since no one else seems to have any answers.) (converted from comment)

The [`IScratchWorkspaceFactory`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IScratchWorkspaceFactory2_Interface/0025000007zv000000/) interface sounds like it will do what you want - instead of creating your `workspace` variable using `IWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile`, try creating a scratch workspace instead? According to the documentation it will be automatically cleaned up when your application exits.

Just remember to use a different workspace for your final output. :)